# Validation.Error event giving strange behavior

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, events

I use the `wpf` event called: `Validation.Error` to know in cs code when there is a validation error on the control.

When the error is created the first time he comes to the event with `ValidationErrorEventAction.Added`.

Once there has been an error on the control, for another error is coming **twice** to the event:

The first time it comes with `ValidationErrorEventAction.Added`.

The second time it comes with `ValidationErrorEventAction.Removed`.

After searching I found this topic on the following question: **[Validation.Error giving strange behavior](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/590dc1d4-045e-4bdf-a84b-d759a5903633/validationerror-giving-strange-behavior)**

Seems that when there has been an error on the control he wants to remove the error and then add a new one, the problem that it makes it in the **opposite** way, it adds a new one first and then remove.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to know.

I keep a dictionary that contains the name of a variable and a list of errors:

```
 private Dictionary<string, List<ValidationError>> invalidList = new Dictionary<string, List<ValidationError>>();
```

Each time an error is added to the variable, I add it to the list of errors, and when the error is cleared I delete it from his errors list.

Then I can see if there is any error on the variable or do not have errors at all.

(I need to know the name of a variable, you can do either dictionary contains control or what you need)

Answer (score 0):

I found a easier way to know if there is still a validation error:

Inside ValidationErrorEventArgs there is a variable that indicates still there is a validation error.

Example of Validation.Error event implementation with this issue fixed:

```
    private void TextBox_Error(object sender, ValidationErrorEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Action == ValidationErrorEventAction.Added)
        {
            ((Control)sender).ToolTip = e.Error.ErrorContent.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            if (!((BindingExpressionBase)e.Error.BindingInError).HasError)
                ((Control)sender).ToolTip = "";
        }
    }
```